# Laravel - GroupBy as Alias

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following in one of my functions but would like to refer to it as an alias named Date:

```php
$loads = $query->get()->groupBy(function($item){
    return Carbon::parse($item->dateTime)->format('F j, Y');
});
```

This `$query` starts off as: `$query = DB::table('loads')...`

and the field `dateTime` is a timestamp.

Is there a proper way to do this to include the alias? Thanks!

//Update with entire Controller Function:

```
public function apiList(Request $request){
    $query = DB::table('loads')
              ->leftJoin('shipments', 'loads.shipmentID', '=', 'shipments.id')
              ->leftJoin('equipment as tractor', 'loads.tractorID', '=', 'tractor.id')
              ->leftJoin('employees', 'loads.driverID', '=', 'employees.id')
              ->leftJoin('customers as shipperCustomer', 'shipments.ship_from', '=', 'shipperCustomer.id')
              ->leftJoin('customers as consigneeCustomer', 'shipments.ship_to', '=', 'consigneeCustomer.id')
              ->select('loads.id','shipments.pro_number','shipments.id','employees.last_name as driver','tractor.unit_id as tractor','loads.dateTime','shipperCustomer.customer_name as ShipperCustomerName','consigneeCustomer.customer_name as ConsigneeCustomerName','shipments.cn_shipfromName as ShipperName','shipments.cn_shiptoName as ConsigneeName');

    if($request->type){
        $query->where('loads.type', $request->type);
    }

    if($request->status){
        $query->where('loads.status', $request->status);
    }

    if($request->type == 1 && $request->status == 2){
        $query->whereIn('shipmentID', function ( $query ) {
            $query->select('shipmentID')->from('loads')->groupBy('shipmentID')->havingRaw('count(*) = 1');
        });
    }

    $loads = $query->get()->groupBy(function($item)
                {
                  return Carbon::parse($item->dateTime)->format('F j, Y');
                });

    return response()->json([
                ['loads'=>$loads],
                ['time'=>Carbon::now()]
            ]);
```

//UPDATE TO SHOW CURRENT RETURNED DATA:

[image]

---

///

Unfortunately, I get the following:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'truckin.loads.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `loads`.`id`, `shipments`.`pro_number`, `shipments`.`id`, `employees`.`last_name` as `driver`, `tractor`.`unit_id` as `tractor`, `loads`.`dateTime` as `loadsDT`, `shipperCustomer`.`customer_name` as `ShipperCustomerName`, `consigneeCustomer`.`customer_name` as `ConsigneeCustomerName`, `shipments`.`cn_shipfromName` as `ShipperName`, `shipments`.`cn_shiptoName` as `ConsigneeName` from `loads` left join `shipments` on `loads`.`shipmentID` = `shipments`.`id` left join `equipment` as `tractor` on `loads`.`tractorID` = `tractor`.`id` left join `employees` on `loads`.`driverID` = `employees`.`id` left join `customers` as `shipperCustomer` on `shipments`.`ship_from` = `shipperCustomer`.`id` left join `customers` as `consigneeCustomer` on `shipments`.`ship_to` = `consigneeCustomer`.`id` where `loads`.`type` = 1 and `loads`.`status` = 2 and `shipmentID` in (select `shipmentID` from `loads` group by `shipmentID` having count(*) = 1) group by DATE_FORMAT(loads.dateTime, "%M %e, %Y"))"

//Update with Another Return
[image]

//A couple of Updates -- August 30, 2018

Based on your original suggestion, I made the updates but received this error:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'truckin.shipments.pro_number' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select ANY_VALUE(loads.id), shipments.pro_number, shipments.id, employees.last_name as driver, tractor.unit_id as tractor, loads.dateTime, shipperCustomer.customer_name as ShipperCustomerName,consigneeCustomer.customer_name as ConsigneeCustomerName,shipments.cn_shipfromName as ShipperName,shipments.cn_shiptoName as ConsigneeName from `loads` left join `shipments` on `loads`.`shipmentID` = `shipments`.`id` left join `equipment` as `tractor` on `loads`.`tractorID` = `tractor`.`id` left join `employees` on `loads`.`driverID` = `employees`.`id` left join `customers` as `shipperCustomer` on `shipments`.`ship_from` = `shipperCustomer`.`id` left join `customers` as `consigneeCustomer` on `shipments`.`ship_to` = `consigneeCustomer`.`id` where `loads`.`type` = 2 and `loads`.`status` = 1 group by DATE_FORMAT(loads.dateTime, "%M %e, %Y"))"

So I went ahead, and ended up having to do the following due to a cascading failure:

> $loads = $query->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(loads.dateTime, "%M %e, %Y")'), 'loads.dateTime','shipments.id', 'shipments.pro_number','driver','tractor','ShipperCustomerName','ConsigneeCustomerName','ShipperName','ConsigneeName')->get();

Now obviously this isn't right, but it was the only way I could get a return of any sort, which ended up being the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One last approach, change this:

```php
select('loads.id','shipments.pro_number','shipments.id','employees.last_name as driver','tractor.unit_id as tractor','loads.dateTime','shipperCustomer.customer_name as ShipperCustomerName','consigneeCustomer.customer_name as ConsigneeCustomerName','shipments.cn_shipfromName as ShipperName','shipments.cn_shiptoName as ConsigneeName');
```

To this:

```php
selectRaw('ANY_VALUE(loads.id), shipments.pro_number, shipments.id, employees.last_name as driver, tractor.unit_id as tractor, loads.dateTime, shipperCustomer.customer_name as ShipperCustomerName,consigneeCustomer.customer_name as ConsigneeCustomerName,shipments.cn_shipfromName as ShipperName,shipments.cn_shiptoName as ConsigneeName');
```

And leave the groupBy as

```php
$query->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(loads.dateTime, "%M %e, %Y")'))->get();
```

If you want to know more about this solution check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value

Check the example on the link and take care of what im quoting down here:

> The failure occurs because address is a nonaggregated column that is neither named among GROUP BY columns nor functionally dependent on them. As a result, the address value for rows within each name group is nondeterministic. There are multiple ways to cause MySQL to accept the query:
>
> Alter the table to make name a primary key or a unique NOT NULL column. This enables MySQL to determine that address is functionally dependent on name; that is, address is uniquely determined by name. (This technique is inapplicable if NULL must be permitted as a valid name value.)
>
> Use ANY_VALUE() to refer to address:
>
> SELECT name, ANY_VALUE(address), MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;
>
> In this case, MySQL ignores the nondeterminism of address values within each name group and accepts the query. This may be useful if you simply do not care which value of a nonaggregated column is chosen for each group. ANY_VALUE() is not an aggregate function, unlike functions such as SUM() or COUNT(). It simply acts to suppress the test for nondeterminism.
>
> Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. This is equivalent to using ANY_VALUE() with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled, as described in the previous item.

Comment: How would I go about adding the function to that though? Normally, I would be fine with that but because of the need I'm in, I had to use the function in that form and need it. Thanks!

Comment: Changing it with how you suggested, using the second block of code, I get the following error returned: {message: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array",…}

Comment: I've added the whole controller function. And I'm trying to put an alias or label in there, it isn't at the moment, it's just being referred to as the date in the group, such as August 29, 2018 rather than Date: August 29, 2018. `dateTime` is the actual field name.

Comment: Check my update, I've made the changes you suggested. It's working this time but without the alias. If you look above, I've shown a screenshot of the return. As you can see, it is only returned as August 28, 2018 - rather than Date: August 28, 2018. The reason I need this is because I have several .each functions within several scripts and I want to say .each(date....) as .each(August 28, 2018...) wouldn't work, as the dates are always changing.

Comment: See the update above with my current error using your suggestion. I feel it's close though!

Comment: I've implemented the change you suggested but now that date grouping is lost (see the above most recent update screenshot).

Comment: See latest updates above.. beginning to think I had to have chosen the worst path to take on this little portion of code...

Comment: And thank you for your time and input, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried `ANY_VALUE(truckin.shipments.pro_number)` for that error? its the same error, so you can fix it the same way

Comment: Also, i really didn't understand why the first solution was of no use to you? the one with the collection groupBy instead of the eloquent one...

Comment: I'll try the other ANY_VALUE, but also, I don't think I ever saw where you defined "alias" was the issue, I wasn't trying to just using a term, otherwise I could just use the "loads" and be happy with it, I needed it to be separated by the dates.

Comment: You can use this: `DATE_FORMAT(loads.dateTime, "%M %e, %Y")` as someAlias  to calculate your alias and in use it in your groupBy like: `groupBy(DB::raw('yourAlias'))`... i don't think i understand that last comment, since, if you are using the original groupBy, the one in the answer, its already being separated by dates... of course you can use an alias as i say in this comment.

Comment: And hey if there was and easier secure way, i would told you to do it... there's the insecure one, that is altering the `only_full_group_by` configuration option... but NO ONE recommends it...

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration of database at *config/database.php* change strict =>false 
Default it is *true*